# Pgadmin4 cannot connect to my postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  db:
    image: myapp
    container_name: my-database
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypasswd
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - 8000:5432
    volumes:
      - /path/to/my/migrationsV1_0__audit_table.sql
      - //path/to/my/migrations/V1_1__tables.sql
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5454:5454/tcp
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@mydomain.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5454
```

Then i $ `docker inspect xxxxxxxx | grep "IPAddress"`

It produces output:

```
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

After docker-compose I enter values to pgadmin as so:

[Pgadmin_capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcXzg.png)

Yet pgadmin gives error:

Unable to connect to server

timeout expired.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration PostgreSQL database has 5432 port (it is default value).
Are you sure in this line?

```
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5454
```

Try to replace it with

```
PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5432
```

Comment: Same error produced with changing line to PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5432.

Answer (score 0):

for a workaround to this issue, just run the container with **--user=root** (in docker-compose use **user: root**)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the gateway address of Postgres container.  Use `docker inspect xxxxxxxx | grep Gateway` to get it. I guess in your case it would be `172.17.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my pgadmin container didn't shared the DB container's network.
So, you should run this command.

```
docker network inspect NETWORK <YOUR DB CONTAINER'S NETWORK>
```

And if it doesn't, run this command

```
docker network connect <YOUR_DB_CONTAINER'S_NETWORK>  <YOUR_PGADMIN_CONTAINER'S NAME>
```